# Shift-A only gives option to add Mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> immediately takes me to the *add mesh options*. I'm trying to add an armature, but I cannot seem to be able to find a way. Even the "create" tab only has an *Add Meshes* option. I remember that the first time I used <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, I had to hover over meshes first, then select my object type...but I've never had to take that first step since and I do not know how to undo it. Help?

Comment: Make sure that you are in **Object** mode (press tab to exit **Edit** Mode)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you are in [*Object Mode*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/introduction.html#object-mode) if you'd like to add a *new primitive* or *new object* to the scene.

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/introduction.html):

> Creation of a mesh primitive typically starts by adding a mesh object
>   in Object Mode. Limited types of editing such as size, location, and
>   orientation can be accomplished in Object Mode. Object Mode also
>   provides the means to Join and Group multiple mesh primitives.

Answer (score 1):

Many tutorials tell to <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> in *Edit Mode* to add a new bone to your armature. I found that sometimes, however, in *Edit Mode* <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> brings up the *Add New Mesh* menu even when I selected my armature, instead of adding a bone.

It's not only necessary to be in the right mode to get the action you expect, but to enter the right mode in the correct order *after* doing certain actions in another mode.

To get consistently get <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> to add the bone to the existing armature (and not get the add mesh menu), it was necessary to

1. Deselect everything. In *Edit Mode*, put the cursor where you want the new bone to appear.
2. Go to *Object Mode* and select the armature.
3. Go back to *Edit Mode*. Now do <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>, and the new bone will appear at the cursor.

Comment: You don't need to do all these steps at all. The only thing you have to pay attention to is to have the right "active object". The active object is the latest selected, and pretty much every operator, tool and editing modes depend on that. So just make sure your latest selected object is the right one. And if it isn't, just shift click it again in object mode to make it active. If you don't need to have multiple objects selected in the first place (which is almost always the case when making an armature), then don't select any other object in the first place.